# enable the php_fileinfo extension

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laravel-5.8

i'm trying to build a form with upload input in laravel 5.8 and use xampp v3.2.3 and add `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` manually into php.ini file but still face with "Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)" error

Comment: In your xampp folder there should be a folder called `php` and inside of it should be a program called `php.exe`. Try running it to see if there are any problems with the dll you have added to the `php.ini` file. If you only get the interactive shell with no errors than you have included the .dll properly and you can verify it trough `phpinfo()`

Comment: Did you restart the xampp server after adding extension=php_fileinfo.dll in php.ini ?

Comment: @SumitDe when i run `php.exe` i get "PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0" error

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your xampp php.ini and uncomment the line :

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

and dont forget to restart apache

Comment: Please check the question. He already added this in `php.ini` file